# Keyboard shortcut to run Automator service not working in Emacs

Tags: keyboard, automator, shortcut

I have an Automator service set up to run an application, and I've bound this to a keyboard shortcut (process described at [Create global shortcut to run command line applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40887) and [Keyboard shortcut (almost) never works for Automator service](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360179)).

This works in the Automator app during testing, and it works on most applications.  However, in Emacs, the shortcut is being captured by the application, so the workflow is not being performed (`s-\ is undefined`).

I have added accessibility to Automator/Finder, but this did not fix the issue.  The keyboard shortcut I am hoping to use is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, however I have tried [different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135616) [combinations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337176) (with and without <kbd>⌘</kbd>; Emacs is capturing everything).

It seems like I somehow need to set the priority of this keybinding to work regardless of the application that is currently selected.  How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot of an Automator window to run a shell script]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Quicksilver](https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver) for this. I have it set up to run when I hit Opt+Space, and I have a folder full of Automator applications that it indexes. Just train it to open your program when you type a certain letter (you can use ‘synonyms‘ if the letter you want doesn't appear in the name of the program) and it will work in any application.